# Help About Crystal Report sorting

Tags: .net

Dear Friends, 
I face a problem in crystal report that I fetched data from two tables 1 is Invoice Table and other one is Payment table. Its a kind of account software problem. Is that I want to make a Ledger or A/C statement Report but when data is come in report it come in one line but I want to data come from datwiese

Means if I make a invoice 1/1/2011 and also make a payment 1/1/2011 so data come like below

date particular debit credit

1/1/2011 - invoice -20000 
1/1/2011- payment- 20000

but if in payment tables i make two entries so data from invoice also come two times

kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at creating groups in your report for the Invoice data, so that the payments are in the details section.

Have a look at [Creating a grouping report](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_XI.asp?Page=3_2)